# Drop Off Library broken

Tags: library

I have a site for which I added a drop off library by activating the Content Organizer site feature. After some deliberation I decided that I do not want this library, so I manually deleted the library using SharePoint designer.

Next, I decided that I do indeed want this library. The Content Organizer site feature is currently disabled. If I try to enable it I get a runtime server error. Any idea how I can get the drop off library back?

Comment: How did you delete the list using SharePoint Designer? What error do you get?

Comment: @PerJakobsen It was quite a while ago, but I'm pretty sure I deleted the **library** from designer by simply selecting it and clicking delete. The error I'm getting is when I'm trying to re-enable the Content Organizer site feature.

Comment: @PerJakobsen - The error is a general server error. (An application error occurred on the server.)

Comment: I've just checked with SP2010 SP1. In there I can't delete the list using SPD, but have to use powershell to set AllowDeletion=true and I get the list back by activating the feature again

Comment: Do you have access to the server? There should be a even better error in the ULS logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not everything is lost - please check if this library doesn't exist in recycle bin (or second-stage recycle bin).

Comment: Unfortunately, the library was deleted more than 30 days ago, so its not in the recycle bin